# Ionic-2 : Pass body through post method in native HTTP cordova plugin

Tags: http, angular, ionic2

How to pass body through the post method of native cordova HTTP plugin in Ionic-2

Comment: you do not need any plugins for ``http`` methods in ionic. You can import angular http module in ionic.

Comment: I follow this link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/http/, but I cannot pass the body. @raj

Comment: is there any specific reason for using native plagin?

Comment: yeah, it has lot of benifits such as 'Background threading - all requests are done in a background thread' and 'SSL Pinning' etc @raj

Comment: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP
The second parameter is the body for post request.

Comment: server doesn't accept the body @SurajRao

Comment: The `cordova-HTTP` plugin only supports _POST_ as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and unfortunately does not support _POST_ as `application/json`, this could be why the server isn't accepting the body @VishnuRapposol.

Answer (score 0):

From the ionic 2 documentation, you can pass `body` like this.

```
import { HTTP } from 'ionic-native';
let body = { data: "value" } \\body which you want to send ;
let header = { Authorization: "OAuth2: token" };
HTTP.post('http://ionic.io', body, header)
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

  });
```

Comment: does the header is necessary? @raj

Comment: But it donot work for me.@raj code:
let credeData = JSON.stringify({username:this.credential.username, password:this.credential.password});
    let link = 'http://100.000.0.70/convoy/loginsignup/login';
    HTTP.post(link, credeData, {}).then(data=>{
      alert(data.data);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      alert(error.error);
    });

Comment: please indend the code when posting on stackoverflow. You can use `` for it.

Comment: yeah ofcoz

let credeData = JSON.stringify({username:this.credential.username, password:this.credential.password});
    let link = 'http://100.000.0.70/convoy/loginsignup/login';
    HTTP.post(link, credeData, {}).then(data=>{
      alert(data.data);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      alert(error.error);
    });

Comment: remove ``JSON.stringify`` from the code and pass   let credeData = {username:this.credential.username, password:this.credential.password}

Comment: 'let credeData = {username:this.credential.username, password:this.credential.password};
    let link ='http://100.000.0.70/convoy/loginsignup/login';
    HTTP.post(link, credeData, {}).then(data=>{
      alert(data.data);
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      alert(error.error);
    });'

Comment: I remove the JSON.stringify, but it doesn't work .  @raj

Comment: the server doesn't recieve the body. Its empty when i check in server

Comment: add http to domain

Comment: I already add, request is recieved by server, but the body is empty @raj

Comment: print the body to console and see if its there

Comment: Now i get the body at server as this: password=d&username=d,
NB: i use d as username and password, how to get them as JSON object

Comment: depends on your backend

Comment: i am using php code on the server, '$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
   if(isset($postData)){
    
    echo $postData;
   }
   else{
    echo "no data";
   }'

it results like this:password=d&username=d

Comment: at seems native http is not able to sending json as data, where you able to resolve this?

Comment: @VishnuRapposol Just set this.setDataSerializer("json") before post call;

Answer (score 0):

Just set this.setDataSerializer("json") before post call;